# Java spring: datatable not working using DAO and Serializable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, serializable

I am trying to populate my jsp data table using (Java spring, hibernate, mysql, jquery, javascript)
and design of DAO and using library Serializable.

Problem is that no data is showing on web page although table is having some rows in database.

Controller Class:

```
@Autowired
private BrickDAO brickDAO;

@Autowired
private BrickDetDAO brickDetDAO;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManagementController.class);

@RequestMapping(value="/bricks", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showManageBricks(@RequestParam(name="operation", required=false) String operation) {


        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");

        mv.addObject("userClickManageBricks", true);
        mv.addObject("title", "Manage Bricks");
        Brick nBrick = new Brick(); 



        mv.addObject("brick", nBrick);

        if(operation!=null) {

            if(operation.equals("brick"))
            {
                mv.addObject("message", "Record Submitted Successfully!");
            }
        }

        return mv;
    }


@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/brick", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showEditBricks(@PathVariable int id) {


    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");

    mv.addObject("userClickManageBricks", true);
    mv.addObject("title", "Manage Bricks");
    Brick nBrick = brickDAO.get(id);

  mv.addObject("brick", nBrick);



    return mv;
}



@RequestMapping(value="/bricks", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleProductSubmission(@Valid @ModelAttribute("brick") Brick mBrick, BindingResult results, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {



    if(results.hasErrors())
    {

        model.addAttribute("userClickManageBricks", true);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Manage Bricks");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Validation failed for Product Submission");

        return "page";
    }

    logger.info(mBrick.toString());

    if(mBrick.getId() == 0) {

        brickDAO.add(mBrick);

    }
    else
    {
        brickDAO.update(mBrick);
    }



    return "redirect:/manage/bricks?operation=brick";

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/brickdetail", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String managePostCategory(@ModelAttribute("brickdetail") BrickDetail mBrickDetail, HttpServletRequest request) {                 
    brickDetDAO.add(mBrickDetail);      
    return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("Referer") + "?success=category";
}



@ModelAttribute("brickdetail")
public List<BrickDetail> getBrickDetail() {
    return brickDetDAO.list();
}
```

DTO CLASS:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id; 

@Column(name = "supplier_name")
private String supplier_name;
@Column(name = "brick_color")
private String brick_color;
@Column(name = "date")
private String date;
@Column(name = "mhl")
private String mhl;
@Column(name = "amount_paid")
private double amount_paid;
@Column(name = "excess_paid")
private double excess_paid;
@Column(name = "total_amount")
private double total_amount;
@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;
@Column(name = "truck_no")  
private String truck_no;
@Column(name = "warehouse") 
private String warehouse;
@Column(name = "brick_size")    
private double brick_size;



public int getId() {
    return id;
}



public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public String getSupplier_name() {
    return supplier_name;
}



public void setSupplier_name(String supplier_name) {
    this.supplier_name = supplier_name;
}



public String getBrick_color() {
    return brick_color;
}



public void setBrick_color(String brick_color) {
    this.brick_color = brick_color;
}



public String getDate() {
    return date;
}



public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}



public String getMhl() {
    return mhl;
}



public void setMhl(String mhl) {
    this.mhl = mhl;
}



public double getAmount_paid() {
    return amount_paid;
}



public void setAmount_paid(double amount_paid) {
    this.amount_paid = amount_paid;
}



public double getExcess_paid() {
    return excess_paid;
}



public void setExcess_paid(double excess_paid) {
    this.excess_paid = excess_paid;
}



public double getTotal_amount() {
    return total_amount;
}



public void setTotal_amount(double total_amount) {
    this.total_amount = total_amount;
}



public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}



public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}



public String getTruck_no() {
    return truck_no;
}



public void setTruck_no(String truck_no) {
    this.truck_no = truck_no;
}



public String getWarehouse() {
    return warehouse;
}



public void setWarehouse(String warehouse) {
    this.warehouse = warehouse;
}



public double getBrick_size() {
    return brick_size;
}



public void setBrick_size(double brick_size) {
    this.brick_size = brick_size;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "brick [id=" + id + ", supplier_name=" + supplier_name + " ,  brick_color="+brick_color+", truck_no=" + truck_no + ", date=" + date
            + ", amount_paid=" + amount_paid + ", excess_paid = "+excess_paid +", total_amount = "+total_amount+", brick_size="+brick_size+",  mhl="+mhl+", quantity="+quantity+" , warehouse="+warehouse+"]";
}
```

}

DAO INTERFACE

public interface BrickDAO {

```
Brick get(int brickId);
List<Brick> list(); 
boolean add(Brick brick);
boolean update(Brick brick);
boolean delete(Brick brick);

List<Brick> getBricksByParam(String param, int count);  
}
```

DAOImpl:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Override
public Brick get(int brickId) {
    try {           
        return sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                    .get(Brick.class,Integer.valueOf(brickId));         
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {       
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Brick> list() {
    return sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Brick" , Brick.class)
                    .getResultList();
}

@Override
public boolean add(Brick brick) {
    try {           
        sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                    .persist(brick);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {       
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }       
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean update(Brick brick) {
    try {           
        sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                    .update(brick);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {       
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }       
    return false;       
}

@Override
public boolean delete(Brick brick) {
    try {

return this.update(brick);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {       
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }       
    return false;           
}



public List<Brick> listActiveBricksByCategory(int categoryId) {
    String selectActiveBricksByCategory = "FROM Brick WHERE active = :active AND categoryId = :categoryId";
    return sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(selectActiveBricksByCategory, Brick.class)
                    .setParameter("active", true)

                    .setParameter("categoryId",categoryId)
                        .getResultList();
}

@Override
public List<Brick> getLatestActiveBricks(int count) {
    return sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Product WHERE active = :active ORDER BY id", Brick.class)
                    .setParameter("active", true)
                        .setFirstResult(0)
                        .setMaxResults(count)
                            .getResultList();                   
}


@Override
public List<Brick> getBricksByParam(String param, int count) {

    String query = "FROM Brick WHERE  ORDER BY " + param + " DESC";

    return sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(query,Brick.class)
                .setFirstResult(0)
                .setMaxResults(count)
                .getResultList();


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's Entity class not DTO. DTO is Data Transfer Object which can be use to proxy objects.

Comment: sure it is, anyways, on debugging the Id remains 0 and do not increment to 1. This can be due to no selection of table is showing on console. The problem is related with Controller not calling the Entity class or Id setter not incrementing to 1. Therefore, no results are showing in jquery table

Comment: It is a wonderful time to staart using lombok, i know it is not relevant to your question but it will help you in future.